# Getting (not cutting) specific substring from bash string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I would like to get sub-string VALUE1 or VALUE2 from the the string `"VALUE3,VALUE2,VALUE4,VALUE9"` and if there is none of these then my $VAR should be empty.

My String cannot have both sub-strings at the same time so we have only 3 possibilities.

`VAR=VALUE1`
`VAR=VALUE2`
`VAR=NULL`

I would like to do it in one line something like:

```
STRING="VALUE3,VALUE2,VALUE4,VALUE9,VALUE7"
VAR=`echo $STRING | grep -P "(VALUE1|VALUE2)"`
echo $VAR
VALUE2
```

Comment: Using `grep -o -P "(VALUE1|VALUE2)"` did the trick for me, if you need the value to be empty when nothing is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print NULL in case `VALUE1` or `VALUE2` none of them are found.

```
echo "VALUE3,VALUE1,VALUE4,VALUE9" | awk '
{
  if(match($0,/VALUE[12],|VALUE[12]$/)){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    sub(/,/,"",val)
    print val
  }
  else{
    print "NULL"
  }
}'
```

OR to take it into a variable use like:

```
VAR=$(echo "VALUE3,VALUE1,VALUE4,VALUE9" | awk '{if(match($0,/VALUE[12],|VALUE[12]$/)){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/,/,"",val);print val} else{print "NULL"}}')
echo "$VAR"
VALUE1
```

Example of getting `NULL` in output in case neither `VALUE1` nor `VALUE2`:

```
VAR=$(echo "VALUE3,VALUE12,VALUE4,VALUE9" | awk '{if(match($0,/VALUE[12],|VALUE[12]$/)){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/,/,"",val);print val} else{print "NULL"}}')
echo "$VAR"
NULL
```

Comment: I did quick test and it always gives me NULL. I would like to get VALUE1 or VALUE2 if my string has it.

Comment: @dzafer, yes it does that, please check my post once, it worked fine for me.

Comment: Perfect, it works now. I modified it a little. 
I removed $ which is behind VALUE[12]

This one works for me:

VAR=$(echo "VALUE3,VALUE32,VALUE4,VALUE9" | awk '{if(match($0,/VALUE[12]/)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)} else{print "NULL"}}')

Comment: @dzafer, Ok seems there was a corner case in regex where in case VALUE1 or VALUE2 is found at last of line so I have covered that part also now, considering that your actual Input_file will be same as shown samples, cheers.